# how to get element using $refs in vuejs template

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have an `h1` element that will truncate the text if the text is to large to fit on the screen and will show an ellipsis.

I'm trying to check to see whether the ellipsis is active or not by using a ref on the `h1` and then referencing this in my `isEllipsisActive` function, but currently I am getting undefined.

How can I reference my `h1` and check to see if the ellipsis is active?

```html
             <h1
                ref="h1"
                :id="id" 
                :content="productTitle"
                :class="{'productTitle__title--extended': !error}"
                class="productTitle__title --headingExtraLarge"
                itemprop="name"
                elementtiming="title-shown">
              {{ productTitle }}
              {{ isEllipsisActive() }}
            </h1>
```

**js**

```js
     methods: {
        isEllipsisActive() {
          var elmnt = this.$refs.h1;
          return console.log(elmnt.offsetWidth < elmnt.scrollWidth));
        },
      },
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try this concept with [nextTick](https://vuejsdevelopers.com/2019/01/22/vue-what-is-next-tick/) (***nextTick is a comfortable way to execute a function after the data has been set and the DOM has updated.***)

you can checkout the example [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/zealous-fog-qpz33?file=/src/App.vue).

Comment: The error was because DOM was not updated, the rest depends on the condition (elmnt.offsetWidth < elmnt.scrollWidth)

Comment: When that condition is true, `isActive` won't update reactively

Comment: Yeah agree, the user can use this in computed property or can use the watch, I was only intended to make sure that one should use nextTick in order to get something from DOM.

Comment: Maybe you could show OP how to do that, I think he intends for the `<h1>` to know when to show an ellipsis

Comment: Yeah, I got your point, I have updated the code, can you look at this (https://codesandbox.io/s/zealous-fog-qpz33?file=/src/App.vue), BTW thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: There is a lot of code that would have to be repeated for each element, and there is setting refs to data properties. It also wouldn't update reactively if the text width changed, though OP didn't say whether the text will change.  But I think yes it could be used at least :)

Comment: this is great, I'm now trying to watch to see if the value is true or false and then updated a data value, how would I do that?

Comment: Okay, Thanks @Dan

Answer (score 0):

Move your *methods* isEllipsisActive() to *computed* and add vue *nextTick()* to get the **DOM**.